# Hibernate = Setting Cascade options at runtime?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

The Hibernate Doc state:

> "Finally, note that cascading of operations can be applied to an
>   object graph at call time or at flush time. "

Source: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html

Where can this be set? I did not find any options in the for example `save()` methods.

I would be thankful if someone can point me to the API doc where I can set this programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cascading is specified in mapping. [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade) is how you do it with annotations. And [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) it describes it for XML mapping.

---

Update:

I think, the statement that you referred to just says that cascading may occur either at call time or at flush time. It does not imply that you can control it during a call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex! Actually I am however looking how this can be done in the code itself, at runtime. As far as I understand the docs this must be possible, somewhere in the session or the save()/update() methods there must be a flag. But I have not found it yet.

Comment: I think that the statement you quoted does not imply that you can control it programmatically. I updated the answer to reflect my thought.

Comment: thanks Alex. I did some further research after you posting with other keywords and found a forum entry in hibernate forum that seems to support your answer. I am no native speaker but for me the sentence in the hibernate docs sounded like this should be possible at runtime (and from a "usecase/programming" perspective this would make sense to me...) so thanks for your answer!